# Move from one sheet to another sheet in Microsoft excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to go to sheet 2 (A1) on putting put value "X" in cell "C3" in sheet 1. Suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Can you be more clear in what you are wanting to do? It seems like if you are wanting to write an "X" on Sheet 1 cell C3 if Sheet 2 A1 is not empty. In which case writing =IF(Sheet2!A1<>"","X","") into Sheet 1 cell C3 will do what you want.

Comment: Are you talking about physically moving your active location to a cell on another sheet when you put a specific entry in a certain cell?

Answer (score 0):

Place the following *Event Macro* in the Sheet1 Code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Range("C3").Value <> "X" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to put the value that is in `Sheet2 A1` into `Sheet1 C3`, you can put this value in `Sheet1 C3`:

```
='Sheet2'!A1
```